# Baking Partially

Tags: materials, texture-baking

Is it possible to bake some materials and skip some without unjoining parts, with that material, from the mesh ? For example, my mesh has material1, material2 and material3. But i only want to bake materia1 and material3 on the texture. Is it possible ?